# Missing byte-granularity masked store in AVX

Tags: simd, sse, avx

I am migrating code from SSE to AVX. The code uses `_mm_maskmoveu_si128`, which conditionally stores 16 bytes based on a mask. The AVX equivalent would be `_mm256_maskmoveu_si256` for 32 bytes, but this instruction does not exist.

How can I emulate it efficiently ?

Comment: Do you want the NT hint of MASKMOVDQU? Is read/blend/write OK?

Comment: @harold: if unavoidable, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMX/SSE2 byte-masked stores (`MASKMOVDQU`) have NT semantics and are *not* efficient on modern CPUs.  e.g. 10 uops with 6-cycle throughput on Skylake. Or 75 uops with 18 cycle latency on Zen 4.  And unless the mask is all-ones, you have a partial-line NT store which sucks on modern multi-core CPUs.

**If you can do a non-atomic load/`vpblendvb`/store without violating multi-threading correctness, that should work well.**  (This requires AVX2 for `_mm256_blendv_epi8` not just AVX, but presumably whatever you're doing with single bytes in a `__m256i` also requires AVX2.)

---

**The only good masked stores (non-NT) are AVX `vmaskmovps`/`pd`** (and AVX2 `vpmaskmovd/q`) with dword or qword granularity, or **AVX-512BW with byte granularity (`vmovdqu8 mem{k}, ymm`).**

AVX masked stores are very slow on AMD, but AVX-512 masked stores are actually efficient on Zen 4 (single uop apparently).  IDK why they couldn't implement the microcode for `vmaskmovps mem, ymm, ymm` to compare into a mask and use that, like 2 uops instead of 42.  (https://uops.info/).

Both AVX1 and AVX-512 masked stores are efficient on Intel, like 3 uops on Skylake for `vmaskmovps` (port 0 + port 4 (store-data) + port 2/3/7 (store-address).  The port 0 uop is probably a `vpmovd2m k, x/ymm` to take the high bits of dword elements and make a `k` mask, in an internal `k` register usable only by microcode.  Unfortunately it can't micro-fuse the store-address and store-data uops in the front-end either, as usual for instructions with uops in addition to the store.

Comment: An issue is that the writes may have to be done at the end of allocated buffers without overflowing. I might have to shift the accesses then.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Ah, yes, a different cleanup strategy is necessary for the last partial vector; at worst scalar, or if you're doing NT stores anyway to a huge array then maybe still use 128-bit masked stores in the cleanup, especially if you don't care about AMD CPUs.  (Although the last couple vectors are a tiny fraction of a huge array so cleanup optimization is maybe less important.) Ideally you can do a final vector that ends at the end of the array (possibly overlapping with previous stores), especially if the destination is write-only (not in-place modification) to avoid store-forward stall

Comment: I am working on images and rectangular sub-images, the last partial vectors occur on every row and are a pain in the neck. Among others, processing them in a scalar way can be more costly than the vectorized part !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Assign contiguous rows to the same thread so it's ok to `vmovdqu` / `vpblendvb` / `vmovdqu`, so some later bytes get loaded + stored again.  Although that probably creates store-forwarding stalls for the next row.  With some extra logic, you can maybe load the final vector of one row, load the first vector of the next, and then process+store the final vector of the old row, to avoid that.  Or lag the cleanup behind by a row, so the dust has settled on the full vectors before you come back and load+store the last vector?  Or an overlapping final vector ending at the end of the row?

Comment: In sub-images, the rows are not contiguous. Another issue is that the rows may be aligned arbitrarily. This is why I would favor conditional loads/stores.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Well tough :(.  Without AVX-512, x86 doesn't have an efficient byte-masked store.  (`_mm_maskmoveu_si128` exists but is not efficient, slow on its own, and evicting the line from all levels of cache with its NT semantics.)  So you need to do something else.  If you can avoid conflicts between threads, load/blend/store is fully safe and doesn't require alignment, and is what I'd be trying to use.  AVX masked stores with dword granularity are efficient on Intel but not AMD (including Zen 4 surprisingly, even though its AVX-512 masked stores are good)